# Variable keeps getting reset to its original value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My code :

```
function send() {

    var nop = 6;

    var send_this = {
        nop: nop
    };

    $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            data: send_this,
            url: "example.com",
            success: function(r) {

                var obj = JSON.parse(r);

                nop = obj.nopval;

                /* some other stuffs*/

            }

        )
    };

}
```

Now, since I already set the `nop` to 6 , it will pass 6. But on returning, the json response `obj.nopval` will return 12 which I want to set to `nop`. So that next time it sends 12 and return 18 and so on....

What happening here is , it is sending 6 and returning 12 but sending 6 again and returning 12 again. The variable is not getting updated.

Comment: what happens is that when you are calling send() function, you are basically assigning value of nop to 6 every time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are declaring and initializing the `nop` variable inside your function, so it will start off at `6` every time the function is called. `nop` needs to exist somewhere outside your function in order for the changes to persist:

```
var nop = 6; // outside the function

function send() {
    var send_this = {
        nop: nop
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: send_this,
        url: "example.com",
        success: function(r) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(r);
            nop = obj.nopval;
            /* some other stuff*/
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your variable outside the function , you are using it in the ajax callback function so everytime you run the function it will reset the value to 6.